# Error with "Where" clause in trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

I'm getting the below error when trying to compile this trigger. The column "POD" is in my OEF_ITV_NDN table, but I haven't worked with triggers much to know why it is saying it is an invalid identifier.

> > Compilation failed, line 77 (09:19:41) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are .relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
> >     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "POD": invalid identifierCompilation failed, line 5 (09:19:41) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
> >     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

```
create or replace TRIGGER "OEF_ITV_NDN_TRU" BEFORE  
  UPDATE ON OEF_ITV_NDN FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
  :NEW.UPDATED_DATE := SYSDATE;  
  :NEW.UPDATED_BY := NVL(V('P1_USER_ID'),USER);
  BEGIN   
    SELECT  
    DECODE(:OLD.CHY_ATD_DATE, :NEW.CHY_ATD_DATE, DECODE( <br>
            :OLD.CHY_ETD_DATE, :NEW.CHY_ETD_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.CHY_ATA_DATE, :NEW.CHY_ATA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.CHY_ETA_DATE, :NEW.CHY_ETA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.DLVRY_ATA_DATE, :NEW.DLVRY_ATA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.DLVRY_ETA_DATE,:NEW.DLVRY_ETA_DATE,DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.AVAIL_FOR_DLVRY_DATE,:NEW.AVAIL_FOR_DLVRY_DATE,DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.HAIRATON_ATD_DATE, :NEW.HAIRATON_ATD_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.HAIRATON_ETD_DATE, :NEW.HAIRATON_ETD_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.HAIRATON_ATA_DATE, :NEW.HAIRATON_ATA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.HAIRATON_ETA_DATE, :NEW.HAIRATON_ETA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.TERMEZ_ATA_DATE, :NEW.TERMEZ_ATA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.TERMEZ_ETA_DATE, :NEW.TERMEZ_ETA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.UZ_BORDER_ATA_DATE, :NEW.UZ_BORDER_ATA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.UZ_BORDER_ETA_DATE, :NEW.UZ_BORDER_ETA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.SHER_KHAN_ATD_DATE, :NEW.SHER_KHAN_ATD_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.SHER_KHAN_ETD_DATE, :NEW.SHER_KHAN_ETD_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.SHER_KHAN_ATA_DATE, :NEW.SHER_KHAN_ATA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.SHER_KHAN_ETA_DATE, :NEW.SHER_KHAN_ETA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.TJ_BORDER_ATA_DATE, :NEW.TJ_BORDER_ATA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.TJ_BORDER_ETA_DATE, :NEW.TJ_BORDER_ETA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.KG_BORDER_ATA_DATE, :NEW.KG_BORDER_ATA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.KG_BORDER_ETA_DATE, :NEW.KG_BORDER_ETA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.KZ_BORDER_ATA_DATE, :NEW.KZ_BORDER_ATA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.KZ_BORDER_ETA_DATE, :NEW.KZ_BORDER_ETA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.RU_BORDER_ATA_DATE, :NEW.RU_BORDER_ATA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.RU_BORDER_ETA_DATE, :NEW.RU_BORDER_ETA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.BY_BORDER_ATA_DATE, :NEW.BY_BORDER_ATA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.BY_BORDER_ETA_DATE, :NEW.BY_BORDER_ETA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.POD_OUTGATE_DATE, :NEW.POD_OUTGATE_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.POD_ATA_DATE, :NEW.POD_ATA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.POD_ETA_DATE, :NEW.POD_ETA_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.POE_ATD_DATE, :NEW.POE_ATD_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.POE_ETD_DATE, :NEW.POE_ETD_DATE, DECODE(<br>
            :OLD.RDD, :NEW.RDD, :OLD.MAX_EVENT,'RDD'),<br>
            'ETD POE'),<br>
            'ATD POE'),<br>
            'ETA POD'),<br>
            'ATA POD'),<br>
            'Outgate JN4'),<br>
            'ETA BY Border'),<br>
            'ATA BY Border'),<br>
            'ETA RU Border'),<br>
            'ATA RU Border'),<br>
            'ETA KZ Border'),<br>
            'ATA KZ Border'),<br>
            'ETA KG Border'),<br>
            'ATA KG Border'),<br>
            'ETA TJ Border'),<br>
            'ATA TJ Border'),<br>
            'ETA Sher Khan'),<br>
            'ATA Sher Khan'),<br>
            'ETD Sher Khan'),<br>
            'ATD Sher Khan'),<br>
            'ETA UZ Border'),<br>
            'ATA UZ Border'),<br>
            'ETA Termez UZ'),<br>
            'ATA Termez UZ'),<br>
            'ETA Hairaton AF'),<br>
            'ATA Hairaton AF'),<br>
            'ETD Hairaton AF'),<br>
            'ATD Hairaton AF'),<br>
            'Avail For Dlvry at FOB'),<br>
            'ETA Delivery'),<br>
            'ATA Delivery'),<br>
            'ETA CHY'),<br>
            'ATA CHY'),<br>
            'ETD CHY'),<br>
            'ATD CHY')<br>
    INTO :NEW.MAX_EVENT  
    FROM DUAL<br>
    WHERE OEF_ITV_NDN.POD = 'JN4';

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN  
    :NEW.MAX_EVENT := 'ERRORED';  
  END;  
END;
```

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears to be that you are querying from the `dual` table but trying to reference a column in the `OEF_ITV_NON` table.

```
 FROM DUAL
WHERE OEF_ITV_NDN.POD = 'JN4';
```

is not valid.  If your query is against the `dual` table, you can only reference columns from the `dual` table.  If your query was against the `oef_itv_non` table, you could reference the `pod` column.  But that would return, presumably, multiple rows rather than the 1 row that you expect.  And it would throw a mutating table exception since that's the table the trigger is defined on.

It isn't obvious to me what that `WHERE` clause is supposed to accomplish for you so it's hard to guess what you really want.  My best guess is that you only want to assign the `:new.max_event` column a value if the `:new.pod` column has a value of `JN4'.  If that's the case, use an`IF` statement

```
IF( :new.pod = 'JN4' )
THEN
  :new.max_event := DECODE( ...
END IF;
```

Your entire `decode` statement is also rather confusing.  I'd have to work out what that is actually trying to accomplish to figure out how to rewrite it.  It seems highly likely, though, that you could do whatever it is you're trying to do without nested `decode` statements using a single `decode` with many arguments or using a standard `case` statement.

Maybe you want

```
IF( :new.pod = 'JN4' )
THEN
  :new.max_event := (CASE WHEN :OLD.CHY_ATD_DATE != :NEW.CHY_ATD_DATE
                          THEN 'ATD CHY'
                          WHEN :OLD.CHY_ETD_DATE != :NEW.CHY_ETD_DATE
                          THEN 'ETD CHY'
                          ...
                      END);
END IF;
```

Comment: An IF statement does seem like the better way to go. The decode statement goes through all of the columns (that have a date) and when it gets to a column that has a new value it stops and sets "Max_Event" equal to that column's name. Basically my customer wants to be able to look 2 columns to determine what was updated last and when it was updated. there are about 6 different values that the POD could be and the reports use different columns so I have to make a new "DECODE" statement for each POD.

Comment: @Doolius - A single `case` statement with a number of `when` conditions would seem a much clearer way to express that logic.  Particularly if any of these columns is potentially nullable.

Comment: So as in, "case when pod = 'jn1' then select....from dual when pod = 'xxx'" then select....from dual"?

Comment: @Doolius - It doesn't sound like you need `dual` or a `select` statement at all.  I updated my answer with an example of the `case` statement that you might want.

Comment: It is my understanding that with case statements, only one "when" can be true.(that might not be correct tho) It is possible that the user will update both of those columns. Would it stop and set a value for Max_Event when one of the "when" statemnts is true? As in, with your example, Max_Event would be equal to 'ATD CHY' because that is the first "TRUE" statement it came across?

Comment: @Doolius - The `CASE` statement will stop evaluating conditions once it finds one that is true.  It's possible that every `WHEN` statement would be true if it were evaluated, that's perfectly legal, the `CASE` will just return the value from the first branch that was true.

Comment: @Doolius - Do be careful about `null` values if any of these columns are nullable and make sure that you realize that null is never equal to or unequal to any other value, including null.  `decode` handles null comparisons a bit idiosyncratically.

Comment: Almost all of the columns will initially be null. And the columns are in order by the column most likely to be updated recently to the column most likely to have been updated when the record was created. To handle the NULLS would decode need to be before each :OLD/:NEW? As in "Case When (DECODE(:OLD...) != DECODE(:NEW....)"? Or is there a better way to handle nulls to make the code see that if :NEW... = NULL it is automatically equal to the :OLD... value?

Comment: @Doolius - It depends.  You may just want an `NVL( :new.column, date '1800-01-01' ) != NVL( :old.columnn, date '1800-01-01')` assuming that Jan 1, 1800 is not a valid value for your columns.  You may want `:new.column != :old.column or (:new.column is not null and :old.column is null)`.  If columns can go from being non-NULL to being NULL, you'd have to consider that case as well.

Comment: Columns can only go from NULL to non-NULL. So I think the NVL should do the job. Will not valid values be skipped over? It wouldn't see the :NEW.column value of '1800-01-01' as different than an :OLD.column value of NULL?

Comment: @Doolius - Assuming that Jan 1, 1800 never exists in the real data, `nvl( :new.column, date '1800-01-01' ) != nvl( :old.column, date '1800-01-01' )` will evaluate to TRUE if `:new.column` is NOT NULL and `:old.column` is NULL, it will be TRUE if both have different non-NULL values, and it will be FALSE if both are NULL.  If you ever inserted an actual `date '1800-01-01'` value while the old value was NULL, the condition would evaluate to FALSE which would be incorrect-- that's why you need to choose a value that does not exist in the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a matter of field: you have a trigger on `OEF_ITV_NDN`, so your where clause `WHERE OEF_ITV_NDN.POD = 'JN4';` is invalid: just replace it with `WHERE :NWE.POD = 'JN4';`.